# When I use the facebook login button what information does facebook get?

Tags: facebook

I work in government so we have to be very careful of not only what data we collect but what data we share with others.

We want to use the Login with facebook functionality, but I can find no information anywhere on what data facebook gets from this process. Obviously they know that that user is using our site, but does any other data leak back to them? Everything I can find only talked about what facebook data the site (me) will receive, not what facebook gets (from us). Is this covered in the facebook documentation somewhere?

Comment: Not really. But https://developers.facebook.com/policy#thingstoknow gives you an indication that it might be more than the average user would suspect ...

Comment: I suppose what you should do first is check with your agencies privacy and security requirements. I would be very surprised if a social media login for services meets these requirements. PS: i like your music